# SPFx : how to get all installed custom apps in a web with appweburl?

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

How can i get all installed custom apps in a web with appweburl in spfx webpart.

Answer (score 5):

You can get all webs including `appwebs` with :

```
<SiteURL>/_api/web/webs
```

You will get the app webs with their url.

For your SPFX webpart you can get all webs like:

```
private getAllWebs(): Promise<number> {
    return new Promise<number>((resolve: (title: string) => void, reject: (error: any) => void): void => {
      this.context.spHttpClient.get(`${this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}/_api/web/webs`,
        SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
        {
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata',
            'odata-version': ''
          }
        })
        .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse): Promise<{ value: { Title: string }[] }> => {
          return response.json();
        }, (error: any): void => {
          reject(error);
        })
        .then((response: { value: { Title: string }[] }): void => {

        });
    });
  }
```